# PouchDB query and changes on same view return different results

Tags: pouchdb, cloudant

I have an Angular2 provider service that uses PouchDB to call Cloudant in the backend.

In cloudant, I have two types of documents, user(s) and group(s).

```
USER
====
{
  "_id": "c8835bc37ab524746db1f53dde5f42ba",
  "_rev": "2-981a4194c1b0f10eec5500f908cab108",
  "type": "follower",
  "user": "<<unique name>>",
  "group": "3cf87867c6d8d980679e2e5a320c28c9",
  "status": "accepted"
}

GROUP
=====
{
  "_id": "3cf87867c6d8d980679e2e5a320c28c9",
  "_rev": "2-b8a1716d9bdc86adf644c8e1915d2a6e",
  "name": "<<Group Name>>",
  "type": "group"
}
```

I've written a View in cloudant as below

```
function (doc) {
  if (doc.type === "follower" || doc.type === "admin") {
    emit(doc.user, {"_id": doc.group, "type": doc.type, "status": doc.status});
  }
}
```

The view helps me get the group documents when I db.query with a key="user" and include_docs=true.(since the _id I provided is not of the user but of the group.

Everything was fine until I added the db.changes code. I used the same filter, view and key options as above but this always seems to return the user doc and not the group.

```
this.db.changes({
  live: true,
  since: 'now',
  include_docs: true,
  attachments: true,
  filter: '_view',
  view: 'Users/userGroups',
  key: <<user>>
```

Am I doing something wrong in the changes call ?

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe CouchDB/Cloudant support what you are trying to do for a couple of reasons:

1. There is no mention in the CouchDB documentation that the changes endpoint supports `key`. The documentation also states this for using `_view` as your filter type:

> Moreover, you cannot make such filters dynamic e.g. process the
>   request query parameters or handle the User Context Object - the map
>   function is only operates with the document.

2. CouchDB is testing only whether or not a document is emitted by a view to see if it should be included in changes. It does not seem to process the actual contents that are emitted:

> The special filter _view allows to use existing map function as the
>   filter. If the map function emits anything for the processed document
>   it counts as accepted and the changes event emits to the feed. For
>   most use-practice cases filter functions are very similar to map ones,
>   so this feature helps to reduce amount of duplicated code.

So, `include_docs` will only include the doc that was changed - not the value that was emitted as part of the view.

I think you're going to have to go back to the database to retrieve the groups after a user has changed, or you could do something like store all groups in memory (not sure if feasible), and monitor changes on the groups to keep your in-memory groups up-to-date (using a new view, etc).

CouchDB docs:
http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.0.0/api/database/changes.html#changes-filter-view